# Android play video from Url surfaceview Progressdialog

Tags: android, surfaceview, progressdialog

I working surfaceview. I can load video from URL and I can play this video. Now I want to use ProgressDialog.i want to show ProgressDialog while 'll start video.this is a my source.how I can add this?
P.s this code working perfect but I want to use progressdialog

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener,
    OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayerControl {
String url = "http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp";
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
SurfaceHolder holder;
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

MediaController mcontroller;
Handler handler;
SimpleSideDrawer slide_me;

String log = "";


Button b;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
            "Loading.....", true);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slide);
    slide_me = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
    slide_me.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_menu);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            slide_me.toggleLeftDrawer();

        }
    });
    SurfaceView v = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.screen_tutorial_video_surface);
    handler = new Handler();
    holder = v.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    playVideo();

    ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = ArrayItemDetails
            .GetSearchResults();

    ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));



}

private void playVideo() {
    try {
        mcontroller = new MediaController(this);
        mcontroller.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(url));
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);

        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    handler = new Handler();
    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    try {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        mMediaPlayer.start();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    mcontroller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mcontroller
            .setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.screen_tutorial_video_surface));
    mcontroller.setEnabled(true);

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mcontroller.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

}

public void start() {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

public void pause() {
    mMediaPlayer.pause();
}

public int getDuration() {
    return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public void seekTo(int i) {
    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(1);
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the `progressDialog` in the `onPlay()` method and dismiss it in `onPrepared()` method.
Declare the progressDialog in the onCreate().

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
```

In the onPlay() display the progressDialog

```
progressDialog.show();
```

In the onPrepared() dismissed the progressDialog as the preparing is finished and video is ready to play.

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: maybe you could elaborate on your answer a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *(and tryed to find it a few time until now)* a unique listener to get progress with e.g. current bytes and total bytes. But you could use the [MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html) to do it.

In documentation of MediaPlayer you can find it:

> While in the Started state, the internal player engine calls a user
>   supplied OnBufferingUpdateListener.onBufferingUpdate() callback method
>   if a OnBufferingUpdateListener has been registered beforehand via
>   [setOnBufferingUpdateListener(OnBufferingUpdateListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnBufferingUpdateListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener%29). This callback
>   allows applications to keep track of the buffering status while
>   streaming audio/video.

*See more at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html*

So if you implement the [MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html) the `percent` parameter of that listener could help you.

> **percent** the percentage (0-100) of the content that has been buffered
>   or played thus far

*See more at: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html#onBufferingUpdate(android.media.MediaPlayer, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html#onBufferingUpdate%28android.media.MediaPlayer,%20int%29)*

Hope that I helped you.